# Set Delegate in a UITabBar StoryBoard App

Tags: iphone, ios, delegates, uitabbaritem

I have an application like this:

[image]

Now, I want to set the SubscriptionsViewController (first UIViewController on the left) as the delegate of the UserViewController.
I have created a @property in the UserViewController.. bla bla bla, but now I can't understand how I can set the first UIViewController as the delegate of the second...
If I have a "User" button instad of the "User" UITabBarItem if can do:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    UserViewController *userViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
    userViewController.delegate = self;
}
```

but it doesn't work with UITabBarItems (probably beacause there are no segues (?))

How I can fix this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: hmm... why do you want to set the delegate?

Comment: When I press the done button I can do a [self.delegate getNumberOfSubscribersAndViewsForUsername:userRequested];

Comment: can you just do `someController.delegate = someController.tabBarController`?

Comment: are you trying to set the delegate to your tab bar controller?

Comment: No, I want to set the SubscriptionViewController AS the delegate OF the UserViewController. In this way, when I press the "done!" button in the UserViewController I can call a method of the SubscriptionViewController ([self.delegate getNumberOfSubscribersAndViewsForUsername:userRequested];"

Comment: oh... i see. then you can try `self.delegate = [self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];`